# Operation count of Discrete Fourier Transform and Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-transform

So my task is to compute the discrete fourier transform of a 4-dimensional real vector $x$, which is an easy task. But then I need to count the amount of operations that it took and compare it to how many it would take using the fast fourier transform instead.

The vector that was used: $x = [\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}, 0, \frac{\pi}{2}]^T$

The transform was done as the following:

$y = F_4x = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -i & -1 & i \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & i & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \pi \\  \frac{\pi}{2} \\ 0 \\ \frac{\pi}{2}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \pi \\  \frac{\pi}{2} \\ 0 \\ \frac{\pi}{2}\end{pmatrix}$

So to count the operations that were necessary, I counted for each row 4 multiplications, 3 additions and one extra multiplication when multiplying in the 1/2.

This leads to $4*(4+3+1)=32$ operations. Now in theory DFT has the complexity $O(n^2)$ which in this case would be $16$. Meanwhile the correct answer according to my material is supposed to be $4*2(4+3)=56$ operations which I don't understand.

The complexity of the fast fourier transform is $O(nlog_2 n)$, but in my material the operations are counted as $2nlog_2n$ which I don't understand either.

Comment: The $O$ notation hides a bounded factor. For example, multiplying a $n \times n$ matrix by a vector takes, as you say, $n^2$ multiplications and $n(n-1)$ additions. This is a total of $2n^2-n$ operations, which is $O(n^2)$ even though it is not exactly $n^2$. Moreover in this context since the coefficient matrix is complex and the vector is real, a complex multiplication and a complex addition each take two real operations. So the result is $2(n^2+n^2-n)$ which in this case is $56$.

Comment: (Cont.) It would be even higher if the vector were complex, because a complex-complex multiplication requires four real multiplications and two real additions.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it! So for the fast fourier transform, it is multiplied by 2 because of the complex matrix?

Comment: Well not necessarily, you have to look into the number of complex multiplications and complex additions that are required to do a 4x4 FFT to figure it out. But the fact that the numbers are complex does cause a factor of $2$ to float around.